# Ajax,amcharts,javascript,mongodb,django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, amcharts

I am trying to load two amcharts on submitting two individual forms via AJAX. I am able to load the first amchart but while using the same procedure for the second one I am not able to do it. If I use same div id for the two am charts then I am able to see the second chart in the first charts' div.

Following is the HTML CODE.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Evo Dashboard</title>
    <meta name="description" content="chart created using amCharts live editor" />
       <style>
          #chartdiv {
                width       : 100%;
                height      : 300px;
                font-size   : 11px;  
            }                                       

            .amcharts-export-menu-top-right {
              top: 10px;
              right: 0;
            }       
        </style>

        <!-- amCharts javascript sources -->

        <script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="static/css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="static/css/plugins/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="static/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


    <script type="text/javascript">
     console.log("reached here");
     var prstatsjsonData ='{{prstats}}';
     var publishedVersion='{{pubversion}}';
     var pbverArray = [];
     var version;
     //console.log("prstats ", prstatsjsonData);
     var result=JSON.parse(prstatsjsonData.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
     var pubver=JSON.parse(publishedVersion.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));

    function pbverToArray(){
        pbverArray = $.map(pubver, function(el) { return el; });
        console.log(pbverArray);
        return pbverArray;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

            // calling multiple ajax from a selected version
                $('#selectVersion').change(function(){
                    version = document.getElementById("selectVersion").value;
                    console.log(version);

                     //ajax call to get YVM Stats

                    $('#getSmokeStatsGeneric').one("submit",function(e)
                            {
                                 var YVM_smoke_details = [];
                                   e.preventDefault();
                                   alert("hello");

                                $.ajax({
                                      url:"/getSmokeStatsGeneric/"+version,
                                      type: "GET",
                                      data: {"version":document.getElementById("selectVersion").value},
                                      success:function(data)
                                      {
                                            e.preventDefault();
                                            var result = JSON.parse(data);
                                            console.log(result);
                                            console.log("printing jobs");
                                            var Pass={};
                                            var Fail={};
                                            var Error={};
                                            var Total={};


                                        var chart;
                                        var count;
                                       Pass.type = "Pass";
                                       Pass.count = result.YVM.result[0].PassYVM;
                                       Pass.color="#04D215";

                                       Fail.type = "Fail";
                                       Fail.count = result.YVM.result[0].FailYVM;
                                       Fail.color="#2A0CD0";

                                       Error.type = "Error";
                                       Error.count = result.YVM.result[0].ErrorYVM;
                                       Error.color="#FF0F00";

                                    //    Total.type = "Total";
                                    //    Total.count = result.YVM.result[0].TotalYVM;
                                    //    Total.color="#FCD202";

                                       YVM_smoke_details.push(Pass);
                                       YVM_smoke_details.push(Fail);
                                       YVM_smoke_details.push(Error);
                                       //smoke_details.push(Total);


                                  console.log("chart data :",JSON.stringify(YVM_smoke_details));

                                         var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
                                          "type": "serial",
                                          "theme": "light",
                                          "marginRight": 70,
                                          "dataProvider": YVM_smoke_details,
                                          "valueAxes": [{
                                            "axisAlpha": 0,
                                            "position": "left",
                                            "title": "YVM Performance for today"
                                          }],
                                          "startDuration": 1,
                                          "graphs": [{
                                            "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]: [[value]]</b>",
                                            "fillColorsField": "color",
                                            "fillAlphas": 0.9,
                                            "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                                            "type": "column",
                                            "valueField": "count"
                                          }],
                                          "chartCursor": {
                                            "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
                                            "cursorAlpha": 0,
                                            "zoomable": false
                                          },
                                          "categoryField": "type",
                                          "categoryAxis": {
                                            "gridPosition": "start",
                                            "labelRotation": 45
                                          },
                                          "export": {
                                            "enabled": true
                                          }

                                        });
                          return false;
                          },
                                  error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError)
                                  {
                                      console.log(thrownError);
                                      alert(xhr.status +":"+ xhr.responseText);
                                  }

                                });
                                return false;
                        });



              // ajax call to see the HW stats
               $('#getSmokeStatsHW').one("submit",function(e)
                    {
                    var HW_smoke_details=[];
                       e.preventDefault();
                       alert("hello");

                    $.ajax({
                      url:"/getSmokeStatsHW/"+version,
                      type: "GET",
                      data: {"version":document.getElementById("selectVersion").value},
                      success:function(data)
                      {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var result = JSON.parse(data);
                            console.log("printing HW STATS");
                            console.log(result);
                            var Pass={};
                            var Fail={};
                            var Error={};
                            var Total={};

                            var count;
                           Pass.type = "Pass";
                           Pass.count = result.HW.result[0].PassHW;
                           Pass.color="#04D215";

                           Fail.type = "Fail";
                           Fail.count = result.HW.result[0].FailHW;
                           Fail.color="#2A0CD0";

                           Error.type = "Error";
                           Error.count = result.HW.result[0].ErrorHW;
                           Error.color="#FF0F00";

                        //    Total.type = "Total";
                        //    Total.count = result.YVM.result[0].TotalYVM;
                        //    Total.color="#FCD202";

                           HW_smoke_details.push(Pass);
                           HW_smoke_details.push(Fail);
                           HW_smoke_details.push(Error);
                           //smoke_details.push(Total);

                      console.log("chart data :",JSON.stringify(HW_smoke_details));

                              var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chart2div", {

                                          "type": "serial",
                                          "theme": "light",
                                          "marginRight": 70,
                                          "dataProvider": HW_smoke_details,
                                          "valueAxes": [{
                                            "axisAlpha": 0,
                                            "position": "left",
                                            "title": "HW Performance for today"
                                          }],
                                          "startDuration": 1,
                                          "graphs": [{
                                            "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]: [[value]]</b>",
                                            "fillColorsField": "color",
                                            "fillAlphas": 0.9,
                                            "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                                            "type": "column",
                                            "valueField": "count"
                                          }],
                                          "chartCursor": {
                                            "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
                                            "cursorAlpha": 0,
                                            "zoomable": false
                                          },
                                          "categoryField": "type",
                                          "categoryAxis": {
                                            "gridPosition": "start",
                                            "labelRotation": 45
                                          },
                                          "export": {
                                            "enabled": true
                                          }

                                        });


                      },
                              error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError)
                              {
                                  console.log(thrownError);
                                  alert(xhr.status +":"+ xhr.responseText);
                              }

                            });

                });  


        });


});
     </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
     pbverToArray();
    </script>
    <div id="wrapper">
                <!-- /.row -->
                <div class="row">
                 <label>Select a User</label>
                                        <select id="selectVersion" class="form-control">
                                            <option>Choose a Published Version</option>
                                               <script>
                                                 for(version in pbverArray)
                                                    {  
                                                        document.write('<option value="' + pbverArray[version]+'">' + pbverArray[version] + '</option>');
                                                    }
                                                </script>
                                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                      <form id="getSmokeStatsGeneric" name="getSmokeStatsGeneric" action="/getSmokeStatsGeneric/">
                         <div class="form-group">

                        </div>
                      <input type="submit" value="See YVM Trends">
                      </form>    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
                  <!-- Flot Charts -->
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>YVM Performance for today</h3>  
                            </div>

                            <div class="panel-body">
                            <p class="lead">YVM Performance</p>
                                <div class="flot-chart"  style="height: 315px;">
                                    <div id="chartdiv"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                      <form id="getSmokeStatsHW" name="getSmokeStatsHW" action="/getSmokeStatsHW/">
                         <div class="form-group">
                        </div>
                      <input type="submit" value="See hW Trends">
                      </form>    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
                  <!-- Flot Charts -->

                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>HW Performance for today</h3>

                            </div>

                            <div class="panel-body">
                            <p class="lead">HW Performance</p>
                                <div class="flot-chart"  style="height: 315px;">
                                 <div id="chart2div"></div>   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <!-- /.row -->


                <!-- /.row -->





                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->

        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="static/js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
    <script src="static/js/plugins/morris/raphael.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/plugins/morris/morris-data.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

when I open the chrome browser console I am able to see the following error:

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectors' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://ocifcklkibdehekfnmflempfgjhbedch/include.preload.js:95:33



 morris.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you can't create a new chart in the same container that you already have another chart in. You would first need to destroy the first chart instance by calling [`clear()`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#clear) method on it.

Having said that, there's probably a better way than creating the chart anew. Looking at the code, I suppose that those two charts are identical, save for the data and the title.

Taking this into account, it's always better (not to mention faster) to reuse an already created chart object, by just updating it's title and data.

You can check if the another chart was already created by accessing[`AmCharts.charts`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCharts#charts) array.

After updating any setting and/or data we're just going to call [`validateNow()`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#validateNow) function to take the changes in.

I.e.:

```
if(AmCharts.charts.length) {
  // the chart already exists
  // let's just update it's data and title
  var chart = AmCharts.charts[0];
  chart.valueAxes[0].title = "HW Performance for today";
  chart.dataProvider = HW_smoke_details;
  chart.validateNow(true);
}
else {
  // create new chart
  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    ...
  });
}
```